# Why does Seamus doubt Harry about Voldemort

Tags: harry-potter

I can understand why people who aren't close to Harry disbelieve him when he claims that Voldemort killed Cedric, especially when the Ministry wants to spread the false narrative that Cedric died in a tragic accident, but why do some of his friends, like Seamus, honestly believe that Harry would orchestrate such a lie about Cedric's death and Voldemort? It's not as if Harry had a reputation to warrant the strong suspicion (on the contrary).

I can understand why fear and the propaganda is convincing people that Harry is lying, and in the case of Seamus, his mum's opinion is also a factor, but to have been friends (and in the case of Seamus shared a bedroom) for 5 years with Harry, who doesn't have a reputation of lying (in fact the opposite), and to still suspect strongly that he is orchestrating this dark lie about Cedric's death and Voldemort's return (for what, attention?) doesn't make sense to me.

> “That’s out of order, Seamus,” said Ron, whose ears were starting to
>   glow red, always a danger sign.
>   “Out of order, am I?” shouted Seamus, who in contrast with Ron was turning paler. “**You believe all the rubbish he’s come out with**  about You-Know-Who, do you, you reckon he’s telling the truth?”
>   “Yeah, I do!” said Ron angrily.
>   “Then you’re mad too,” said Seamus in disgust.
>   <sub>—*Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter 11, The Sorting Hat's New Song</sub>

Comment: The answer seems to be in the very quote you provided. Harry himself declared his intention to do so: `"Only you said this morning you’d have done it last night, and no one would’ve seen you. . . . I’m not stupid, you know.”` Even if he didn't have any concrete plans, that's a mighty suspicious thing to say.

Comment: Book 4 - Ron's jelly, book 5- Seammus F and other Gryffindors aren't Harry's close friends so they believe the adults, rumors & ministry propaganda.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I didn't say I was confused why Ron suspected him in the first place (all of Gryffindor did), I said I was confused why Ron continued suspecting him even after Harry continually and repeatedly clarifies the truth. And, as a bit of a tangent, I want to add what Harry *actually* said: *“Bet some of them put it in last night after we’d all gone to bed,”
said Harry. “I would’ve if it had been me . . . wouldn’t have wanted
everyone watching. What if the goblet just gobbed you right back
out again?”*, unless Ron is referring to an undescribed convo they had privately.

Comment: There appear to be two distinct questions here

Comment: @Valorum Not intentionally, the singular question is in the title. I gave *two distinct* examples to back my confusion.

Comment: @Valorum **[cont.]** They seem to be out-of-character moments that rely on a single, repeating phenomena, that Harry is suspected of being a liar by his close friends

Comment: @R.Skeeter It's a sneaky trick in your comment to clump *"Seamus F and other Gryffindors"* together to try to achieve the *"aren't Harry's close friends"*, but it falsely equates Seamus' relationship with Harry with every other Gryffindor's. I explained Seamus' relationship with Harry, how it differs from others who disbelieve Harry, and why it doesn't make sense that he disbelieves Harry.

Comment: about Ron-“He’s jealous!” “Jealous?” Harry said incredulously. “Jealous of what? ... “Look,” said Hermione patiently, “it’s always you who gets all the attention, you know it is. I know it’s not your fault, I know you don’t ask for it . . . but — well — you know, Ron’s got all those brothers to compete against at home, and you’re his best friend, and you’re really famous — he’s always shunted to one side whenever people see you, and he puts up with it, and he never mentions it, but I suppose this is just one time too many. . . .”

Comment: @GhotiandChips - As has been pointed out, the first example and the second example are very different circumstances, years apart. "***Why does Ron doubt Harry about the Goblet of Fire***" is a completely different question (with a different answer) to "***Why does Seamus doubt Harry about Voldemort***"

Comment: About SF - Rommies <> close friends. Harrys friends are Ron, Hermione and later on Neville and Luna.

Comment: @R.Skeeter Not good enough :S they are definitely friends enough, having been roommates, Harry met Seamus' parents etc. that it makes believing Harry orchestrated a dark lie about Cedric's death (for what, attention?) very uncharacteristic

Comment: @Valorum I disagree, and can't really justify it without repeating myself (*they are two **examples** to highlight **the same** ruddy concept that I'm asking **one question** about*), but I changed it nonetheless, out of respect.

Comment: Here's the thing: people are afraid of the unknown. Harry sometimes behaves strangely, has this scar that hurts, has nightmares, speaks parseltongue... is it that far fetched that he sustained some kind of brain damage and imagined things instead of believing a scary story about V. returning? Especially that authority figures, the papers and SF's mom think it's all delusions of a sick mind? They're not that close, Harry never talks openly with SF like he does with his friends...First time the students hear H's story is at the DA meeting.

Comment: @R.Skeeter See, now you could amalgamate a lot of what you said (seems a lot of effort to spend on comments ;) almost as if someone sneakily egged you on into making solid points), clean it up and cite some shizz and turn it into an actual answer, couldn't you?

Comment: It's an interesting question, deserves proper attention. If I'll have time tomorrow, I'll take a stab.

Comment: The Media is a powerful weapon in the wrong hands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since we don't get a lot of insight into Seamus' mindset here, we have to do a certain amount of speculation. That being said, Seamus' reaction is marginally more rational than it might appear.

### Harry doesn't make himself seem credible

It's worth noting that, initially, Seamus actually *is* interested in hearing Harry's point of view; Harry's hostile response is what turns him off (bold is my emphasis, italic from the text):

> "Look...what *did* happen that night when...you know, when...with Cedric Diggory and all?"
>
> **Seamus sounded nervous and eager at the same time.** Dean, who had been bending over his trunk, trying to retrieve a slipper, went oddly still and Harry knew he was listening hard.
>
> "What are you asking me for?" Harry retorted. "Just read the *Daily
>   Prophet* like your mother, why don't you? That'll tell you all you need
>   to know."
>
> "Don't you have a go at my mother," **snapped** Seamus.
>
> "I'll have a go at anyone who calls me a liar," said Harry.
>
> **"Don't talk to me like that!"**
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 11: "The Sorting Hat's New Song"</sup>

Obviously we know that Harry is telling the truth, and that his frustration is at least somewhat justified, but Seamus doesn't. From his perspective, he's being open-minded: he gives Harry an opportunity to tell his side of the story, and is met with frankly *shocking* hostility. Regardless of what he personally believes at this point, the *Daily Prophet* seems like the more credible source; at least they're not making [*ad hominem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) attacks on his mother.

Which leads me to...

### Seamus is quite angry in this scene

It's notable that, as we can see in the quote above, Seamus gets *very* angry once Harry starts making comments about his mother. As soon as this happens, his ability to have a meaningful, intelligent conversation is gone; as anyone who's spent any amount of time on the Internet will tell you, making someone angry is about the worst possible way to convince them of your point of view.

Even if Seamus had agreed with Harry before this - and it seems more likely, given his earlier comments, that he was undecided at best - he *certainly* wouldn't be agreeing with him afterwards. This is by no means a rational position, but it's how our monkey brains think; there have been [studies](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0139193) on this in the context of political opinions, and (again) a cursory skim of the Internet will tell you that it holds for non-political opinions as well.

But all of this is in the context of a single conversation; what about more generally? Why does Seamus still have doubts when he gets up the next morning, presumably (slightly) less angry?

### Harry *still* doesn't act like a credible source

Before the *Quibbler* interview, Harry does very little to make himself seem believable; his attempts to tell his story basically boil down to saying "nuh-uh" at higher and higher volumes, which makes it very easy to believe the story that he's lying, unhinged, or both. Take, for example, his exchange with Umbridge:

> "So we're not supposed to be prepared for what's waiting out there?"
>
> "There is nothing waiting out there, Mr. Potter."
>
> "Oh yeah?" said Harry. His temper, which seemed to have been bubbling just beneath the surface all day, was reaching boiling point.
>
> "Who do you imagine wants to attack children like yourselves?" inquired Professor Umbridge in a horribly honeyed voice.
>
> "Hmm, let's think..." said Harry in a mock thoughtful voice, "maybe *Lord Voldemort*?"
>
> *[...]*
>
> "You have been told that a certain Dark wizard has returned from the dead -"
>
> "He wasn't dead," said Harry angrily, "but yeah, he’s returned!"
>
> *[...]*
>
> "As I was saying, you have been informed that a certain Dark wizard is at large once again. *This is a lie*."
>
> "It is NOT a lie!" said Harry. "I saw him, I fought him!"
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 12: "Professor Umbridge"</sup>

And so on. Again, *we* know that Harry is right, but to the rest of the school he looks like he's throwing a temper tantrum; he acts deranged, so it's easy to believe that he *is*. This is a common [marginalization tactic](http://www.derailingfordummies.com/derail-using-anger/), and it's common because it demonstrably works.

And it's worth remarking that, as soon as Harry actually *does* tell his story, without raving like a lunatic about it, Seamus (and others) actually do start to believe him; Seamus apologizes on literally the same day the *Quibbler* article comes out.

Comment: That is, on the day he sees it in print. +1 excellent, well-argued answer.